# What are some good settings for seeding a ton of torrents? (>10000)

Tags: bittorrent, libtorrent, torrent

I'm running into a lot of trouble when trying to seed a lot of torrents( > 10k) with libtorrent.

They include:

- Choking my network connection
- Tracker requests timing out(libtorrent tracker error)
- When using auto-manage(they go from checking to seeding **very slowly**, even when my active_seeding is set to unlimited.

I used to let them be automanaged, but I'd find that it makes nearly all of them unavailable.

Here are my current settings:

```
    sessionSettings.setActiveDownloads(5);
    sessionSettings.setActiveLimit(-1);
    sessionSettings.setActiveSeeds(-1);
    sessionSettings.setActiveDHTLimit(5);
    sessionSettings.setPeerConnectTimeout(25);
    sessionSettings.announceDoubleNAT(true);
    sessionSettings.setUploadRateLimit(0);
    sessionSettings.setDownloadRateLimit(0);
    sessionSettings.setHalgOpenLimit(5);
    sessionSettings.useReadCache(false);
    sessionSettings.setMaxPeerlistSize(500);
```

My current method is to loop over all my 10k+ torrents, and run torrent.resume(). When using automanage, this basically only starts ~ 50 of the torrents, and the others start about at a rate of 1 torrent per 10 minutes, which wouldn't work. When not using automanage, it chokes my connection.

BUT, when I do only 30 of them, they all seem to seed correctly, so my next plan is try to resume() them in groupings either with a time delay, or after they've received a tracker_reply.

I tried to garner what I could from this, but don't know what my settings should be specifically:

http://blog.libtorrent.org/2012/01/seeding-a-million-torrents/

I'd really appreciate someone sharing their settings for seeding thousands of torrents,

Comment: A better guide on how to optimize libtorrent can be found here: http://libtorrent.org/tuning.html

Comment: Is that on a server or a domestic internet connection?

Comment: Also, can you try explaining a little more why you need to run this many torrents at once? It's not obvious to me from your question.

Comment: @the8472 It could be either. And I'm developing an application that requires a lot of small files being seeded.

Answer (score 2):

> When not using automanage, it chokes my connection.

Since you say it can run either on a hosted server or domestic internet connection then you will have not much of a choice but to throttle torrent startups. Domestic internet connections are generally behind consumer grade routers and possibly CGNAT, both of which have fairly small NAT tables that will eventually choke from concurrently established TCP connections (peer-peer connections, tracker announces) or UDP pseudo-connections (UDP trackers, µTP, DHT)

So to run many torrents at once you will have to limit all active maintenance traffic of that kind so that the torrents are only started to listen passively for incoming connections.